# incline vertical lines of a square in css?

Tags: html, css

I have some square divs in my page which I use like buttons. How can I make the vertical lines a bit inclined without rotating the whole square ?

I want to make a square look like in figure 1 (in green) instead of figure 2 (in red)

Is this possible through css or should I use images ?

[image]

```
html:
<div id="square"></div>

css:
 #square {
 width:50px;
 height:50px;
 display:block;
 background-color:red;
 overflow:hidden
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gmrq1ac4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CSS3 Transform: Skew

```
#square {
    -ms-transform: skew(30deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: skew(30deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: skew(30deg); /* Standard syntax */
    transform-origin: bottom left; /* Prevent the bottom from shifting */
}
```

Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/gmrq1ac4/1/)

Comment: Thanks ! I didn't think it was that simple :$

Comment: I'd add `transform-origin:bottom left;` so the bottom left does not shift: http://jsfiddle.net/gmrq1ac4/2/

Answer (score 2):

Yes, possible with CSS! Like this:

```
#square{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: green;
  border: solid 5px black;
  -webkit-transform: skewX(-25deg); //also use -moz, etc for other vendors
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You need to `transform` your square x part between 20 - 30 deg. please see this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/7r6zqoL6/)

Output window
[image]

Code

```
#square1 {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:red;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin-top:20px;
    border:2px solid #000;
    margin-left:15px;
    clear:both;
}
#square {
    clear:both;
    border:2px solid #000;
    margin-left:20px;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:lightgreen;
    overflow:hidden
    -ms-transform: skew(-30deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: skew(-30deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: skew(-30deg); /* Standard syntax */
}
```

Comment: Umm how is this different from the accepted answer? Please include your code in your answer not just a fiddle and screen shot! Duplicate identical ID's are also bad

Comment: i add my example link and if you want to my code ok i will add this